# Spark ElasticSearch - Struct not found error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch

Im trying to query ElasticSearch from spark. Here is my code.

```
val esURL = "ES.com"
val reader = spark.read
  .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
  .option("es.nodes.wan.only","true")
  .option("es.port","443")
  .option("es.net.ssl","true")
  .option("es.nodes", esURL)
  .option("es.net.http.auth.user","admin")
  .option("es.net.http.auth.pass","pass")
val df = reader.load("store_products")
// df.printSchema()
df.select($"about").show()
```

Here is the schema:

```
root
 |-- about: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- agg: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- attributes: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- spec: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- capacity: string (nullable = true)
```

I tried to extract the about field,  but its giving the following error.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 15.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 15.0 (TID 54, 10.83.228.77, executor 1): org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopParsingException: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalStateException: Field 'about' not found; typically this occurs with arrays which are not mapped as single value
```

Not sure where is the exact problem.

Update:

- Spark version: includes Apache Spark 3.1.2, Scala 2.12
- ES jar file:  elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-7.9.0.jar
- ES Version: 7.9

Comment: What versions of spark and ES are you using. What lib versions are you using as well
some of the configs have changed between versions!

```
val readConfigMap = Map[String, String](
  "es.host" -> ,
  "es.port" -> "443",
  "es.net.ssl" -> "true,
  "es.nodes.wan.only" -> "true",
  "es.index.read.missing.as.empty" -> "true",
  "es.mapping.date.rich" -> "false",
  "es.scroll.size" -> "100",
  "es.scroll.keepalive" -> "true",
  "es.http.retries" -> "3",
  "es.http.timeout" -> "3000"
)

Comment: @Ramachandran.A.G - Added the details in the question

Comment: Have you tried using es.host as opposed to es.node

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too